# How to reach signup page of openiddict authorization server?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, openiddict

I have built opeiddict as separate web application as authorization server. I am stuck with small problem, that is how I can go to user registration page directly though a link from the client web application. Right now I can go to login page, as your sample example:

```
public ActionResult SignIn() {
           // Instruct the OIDC client middleware to redirect the user agent to the identity provider.
           // Note: the authenticationType parameter must match the value configured in Startup.cs
           return new ChallengeResult(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties {
               RedirectUri = "/"
           });
       }
```

Is there a way to go to authentication server Account/Register from client app?

Comment: Syed, Zafrul, please let me know if you need anything more in the way of a response/answer.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can set the url in the redirect.  See the following snippet:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult SignIn()
{
    return new ChallengeResult(
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("SignInCallback", "Account")
        });
}
```

See the docs here: [Initiating the authentication flow](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/guidance-identity-management-for-multitenant-apps/blob/master/docs/03-authentication.md#initiating-the-authentication-flow)